# Starting MySQL on Bash on Ubuntu on WIndows

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I've installed MySQL:

> sudo apt-get install mysql-server

I've tried to start the service:

> sudo service mysql start

But everytime I start it I get the message:

> *Starting MySQL database server mysqld         [fail]

I've tried reinstalling MySQL, killing any related running process, but nothing I've tried this entire week has worked.

I've also tried directly logging into mysql with the command below,

> mysql -u root -p

But I would get the following error message:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Edits: I fixed a typo. I forgot to include "sudo" in the start command. This also did not work for me. I also added in what would happen if I tried to login to MySQL

Comment: Maybe you should ask on "Ask Ubuntu"

Comment: Not sure where you are using Windows in all this???

Comment: If you sudo install, you probably need to sudo start.

Comment: @RiggsFolly He means the new experimental Unix subsystem on Windows

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Ahhh WooHoo I will keep an eye on the answers for this then

Comment: Yep, you need to prepend "sudo" to your service mysql start.  If that doesn't work, check your log file to see why it's failing to start.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my question, I've used "sudo service mysql start" I just forgot to put that in there. Also yes I am using the subsystem that @ÁlvaroGonzález mentioned

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So I was finally able to get MySQL to start.
After doing everything I mentioned above, I looked into the error.log file, located at:

> /var/log/mysql/error.log

I looked into it and the most important lines I found were:

> 2017-05-29T03:51:16.559247Z 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Permission denied
>
> 2017-05-29T03:51:16.559401Z 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
>
> 2017-05-29T03:51:16.559558Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

I opened up Run and opened services.msc (Remember, I'm using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows), and scrolled down to find "MySQL57" The service was running, so I stopped it.

Then I went back to my terminal and ran "sudo service mysql start," which ended up working finally.

Comment: there's no service called like that in my machine
but now I'm aware that some program is using that port